# Can I insert a diagram/image into a part protected word 2003 document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I have worked out how to part protect a document however I am wanting to be able to insert a diagram/image into the unprotected section NOT comments.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the range in the document is unprotected then there should be no problem inserting a diagram into it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Moses, What part of the answer needs expanding?